# RxJS repeat depending on emitted value

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I am trying to `repeat` a promise call depending on the value returned in `condition` field. The following block doesn't work because `v` is undefined and randomly throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'condition' of undefined`

the o/p of console.log is `{ Items: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], condition: 5, time: 1513827310333 }`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nilobarp/3sx2gh2c/)

```
const source = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
  Promise.resolve({
    Items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    condition: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    time: +new Date()
  })
);

source
  .map(val => val)
  .repeatWhen(val => {
    return val.map(v => { // v is undefined
      if (v.condition > 0) {
        return Rx.Observable.of(v);
      } else {
        return Rx.Observable.empty();
      }
    });
  })
  .finally(() => {
    done();
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with an external flag an the source is evaluated for every repetition.

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.defer(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    Items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    condition: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    time: +new Date()
  })
);

let condition = false;

source
  .repeatWhen(notifications => {
    return notifications
      .scan(() => {
        return condition;
      }, false)
      .delay(100)
      .takeWhile(() => {
        return condition;
      });
  })
  .do(x => (condition = x.condition !== 0))
  .finally(console.log("done"))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can also use `defer` to change the external state to per-subscription state: `const repeats = Rx.Observable.defer(() => { let condition; source.do(value => condition = value.condition !== 0).repeatWhen(/* etc. */); });` External state is best avoided.

Comment: @cartant great idea. Will test this and let you know.

Comment: There should have been a `return` in the previous comment's code - before `source`. Then do the `finally` and the `subscribe` on the `repeats` observable, etc.