# How to use Angular RXJS forkjoin with Youtube API to load complete video playlist

Tags: angular, rxjs, youtube-api

I am building a simple Angular app that should list all videos in a Youtube playlist using their API. I use the playlist endpoint as documented here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists.

In short: you can only get 50 videos per call, and if there are more than 50 videos in the requested playlist, you get a "nextPageToken". So, a basic loop would do the job, in theory. I could check if a "nextPageToken" was returned, if yes, make an other call with it, and so on, until I have all videos.

My challenge is that I need to get ALL videos of a list before doing more tasks on a resulting observable. As a novice in RXJS, my grasp around every operator is not great, but I figured that I'd try forkjoin to achieve this.

That being said, common usage I found is :

```
public getAllSources(): Observable<any[]> {
    let response1 = this.http.get(requestUrl1);
    let response2 = this.http.get(requestUrl2);
    let response3 = this.http.get(requestUrl3);

    return forkJoin([response1, response2, response3]);
}
```

The expected result is what I need: an observable that will only emit when all inner observables have finished/emitted. I would apply this with Youtube API endpoints, but the problem is, I only get the nextPageToken needed for subsequent calls after a call is actually made. I can't get all from the start, then use the generated URLs with forkjoin in the same way as this example.

What would be the best way to get the needed result? I suspect that I might be looking at the problem the wrong way.

Comment: You can use `expand` to recursively call an endpoint and use `reduce` to emit once all results have been received. Check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130075/recursively-calling-an-api-using-rxjs-expand-operator).

Comment: @BizzyBob I implemented it in my project and it works beautifully! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BizzyBob do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the solution? If not, I'll post an answer quoting you and show tweaks I did to make it work in my context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively calling an API using RxJS expand operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130075/recursively-calling-an-api-using-rxjs-expand-operator)